# In MongoDB, how do I find and update a particular array element?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Suppose I have the following MongoDB collection, and I'd like to find all documents whose `ratings.by` is `ijk` and update its rating to 6.

In other words, update `{ by: "ijk", rating: 4 }` to `{ by: "ijk", rating: 6 }`. The problem is that I don't know the index of such array element.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "TBD",
  stock: 0,
  info: { publisher: "1111", pages: 430 },
  tags: [ "technology", "computer" ],
  ratings: [ { by: "ijk", rating: 4 }, { by: "lmn", rating: 5 } ],
  reorder: false
}
```

**My Question:** How should I write the `db.collection.update()` function? This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
db.collection.update({
    ratings.by: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $eq: 'ijk'
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        // don't know which index to set. How should I modify this line?
        ratings.rating: 6
    }
}, {
    multi: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)** which identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "ratings.by": "ijk" }, 
    { "$set": { "ratings.$.rating": 6 }},
    { "multi": true }
);
```